# Given preimage area of a triangle, find image triangle area after a transformation

Tags: matrices

Given transformation S:  $$\begin{pmatrix}
    3 & 2 \\
    4 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

If a preimage triangle has an area of 10, what is the area of the image triangle?

Thinking we will be using the matrix area formula for triangles but not really sure how to solve?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You will have more chances to get an answer if you show your work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you learnt about determinants yet?

In that case, the area of the triangle is simply
$10\left\vert\det\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\4&2\end{bmatrix}\right\vert$.

Comment: Yes I have learned about determinants but I am unsure as to why the new area is simply 10 multiplied by the determinant.